# Как запускать функцию из расширения на каждой вновь открытой вкладке браузера?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы расширение в фоновом режиме вносило небольшие изменения на текущей и всех последующих вкладках, при их открытии.

Для разового изменения содержания страницы это не представляет трудности, но как заставить расширение работать в фоне непонятно.

Если кто может помочь конкретным советом или ссылкой на подходящие решения/функции/библиотеки (желательно, с русскоязычной документацией) буду очень благодарен.

Манифест:

```html
{
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color",
  "description": "Change the current page color",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
  "background_page" : "background.html",
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

JS:

```html
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='" + e.target.id + "';"});
 
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
    {code:"var mEl=document.querySelectorAll('*') ; for (var i = 0; i < mEl.length; i++ ){mEl[i].style.backgroundColor='" + e.target.id + "';\
  mEl[i].style.color = 'green';\
  \};"});
 window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
 for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
 divs[i].addEventListener('click', click);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо, что бы расширение запускалось каждый раз при открытии новой вкладки?

Если так, то вы можете в манифесте (**manifest.json**) указать файл **js**, который будет выполняться для каждой вновь открытой вкладки браузера.

Документация [здесь](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Хорошее описание, как создать расширение на [habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147111/).

Пример:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```